# Unable to access Query String parameters inside a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Here's what I have done so far,

This is the Route that I have defined for a page

```
<Route path='emails/user/view/:id' component={AccountEmails} />
```

And here's where the Component is being rendered

```
const AccountEmails = ({params: {id}}) => <ReceiptsListBox url={"/api/accounts/"+id+"/receipts.json"}></ReceiptsListBox>
```

Now, within the `render()` method of the component, I tried to `console.log(this.props.location.query)` unfortunately `this.props.location` is undefined.

Here's the YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBxMljq9GSE) that I have referred to.

react-router version 2.8.1 and react version 15.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
const AccountEmails = props => {
    const {id} = props.params;
    return  <ReceiptsListBox 
                url={"/api/accounts/"+id+"/receipts.json"} 

                {...props}       // =====> notice this part, important

            </ReceiptsListBox>
}
```

**Reason is:** You are passing only url in props, not all the props values that `AccountEmails` receives from Routes, because of that `location` is not available inside `ReceiptsListBox` component.

Solution is pass all the props that `AccountEmails` component receive along with one extra url value, by that way `location` will be available inside `ReceiptsListBox` component.